# Saving string values from stdin into struct field

Tags: c, struct

Im trying to assign values from stdin (that I get using `char *gets(char *str)`) in the `while` loop but it doesn't seem to work. I have seven `automobile` struct` and I want that at every iteration the variable I'm triyng to fill with the input changes form a1.marca to a2.marca. I tried this strategy but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    struct automobile
    {
        char marca[15];
        char modello[20];
        char targa[7];
        unsigned cilindrata;
    } a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7;
    
    int main()
    {
        int Nauto=7, a=0;
        char const id[3]={'a', '1', '\0'};
        a=1;
        while (Nauto>0)
        {
            printf ("Inserisci i dati della %d%c auto\n", a, 167);
            printf ("Marca: ");
            gets(id.marca);
            printf ("Modello: ");
            gets(id.modello);
            printf ("Targa: ");
            gets(id.targa);
            printf ("Cilindrata: ");
            scanf ("%d", &id.cilindrata);
            a++;
            Nauto--;
            id[2]=a;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Never ever use `gets`. It's a dangerous function which have even been removed from the C specification. Use e.g, [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: Thanks but for the other problem?

Comment: As for your problem, to begin with `1 != '1'`. I suggest you start by looking at e.g. [this ASCII table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) (ASCII being the most common character encoding). Also, you do remember that array indexes are *zero-based*? Meaning the second element in an array have index `1`.

Comment: do not mix `fgets()` and `fscanf()`. https://www.go4expert.com/articles/solution-using-scanf-fgets-c-t27148/

Comment: Your `id` variable is not a structure type, how could you use it as struct. Another thing is it `const` qualified meaning that you cannot change its value afterwards.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks but how can 1 != '1' help me?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can you suggest me a way to do what I have to do? If you don't understand (sorry for bad english) I'll try to explain myself better

Comment: Does your code even compile? if it doesn't what are the errors/warnings?

Comment: The integer `1` has the numeric value `1`. The character `'1'` has the numeric value `49` in ASCII. If you want the *character* `'1'` then `a=1` is wrong.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so how can i write fgets(a1.marca); so that in the second reiteration a1 become a2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have an array of automobiles and then in the while loop you can index the array. A for loop will be easier than a while loop:

```
struct automobile
{
    char marca[15];
    char modello[20];
    char targa[7];
    unsigned cilindrata;
} a[6];

for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    fgets(a[i].marca, sizeof(a[i].marca), stdin);
    // ....
}
```

Note the use of `fgets`, which is more safe than `gets` as you can specify the number of characters to read.

The safest way to specifcy the number of characters to read is by using `sizeof`. Here it takes `sizeof(a[i].marca)` charaters. The compiler will replace this with the size in compile-time, even though `a[i]` looks like runtime. This is safest because if you later decide to change the size of `marca`, the size to read is changed here automatically.

The specification of `fgets` says it reads up to `n-1` charactes so there will be room for the terminating null character of the string. For the meaning of the last parameter I refer you to the documentation of `fgets`. Read it carefully to understand its behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain what the last two argument of the fgets?

Answer (score -1):

I got what you were trying to do. In C, it's not practical to allocate static structs and using it like that. Instead, you can allocate it dynamically. Here's my running code example below (I tried to maintain your code ):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define maxNauto 7

typedef struct
{
    char marca[15];
    char modello[20];
    char targa[7];
    unsigned cilindrata;
} automobile;

int main()
{
    int Nauto=0, a=0;
    a=1;
    automobile** autos = (automobile**) malloc(maxNauto * sizeof(automobile*)); // Allocates an array of automobiles to
                                                                            // Support each index of an automobile struct
    while (Nauto < maxNauto)
    {
        autos[Nauto] = (automobile*) malloc(sizeof(automobile)); // Allocate each automobile struct

        printf ("Inserisci i dati della %d%c auto\n", a, 167);

        printf ("Marca: ");
        getc(stdin); // Gets the '\n' char from the stdin, so it's not detected as an input in fgets or scanf
        fgets(autos[Nauto]->marca, 15, stdin);
        printf ("Modello: ");
        fgets(autos[Nauto]->modello, 20, stdin);
        printf ("Targa: ");
        fgets(autos[Nauto]->targa, 7, stdin);
        printf ("Cilindrata: ");
        scanf ("%d", &(autos[Nauto]->cilindrata));

        a++;
        Nauto++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to first allocate an array of pointers, and then allocate each `struct automobile` separately. Furthermore, the `getc(stdin)` call will just read the first character from `stdin`, it doesn't make subsequent `fgets()` or `scanf()` calls ignore newlines.